# How to customize the select arrow in a "Multiselect" component using "multiselect-react-dropdown" package?

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, multi-select

I want to create a multi select dropdown using **multiselect-react-dropdown** package. But, I cannot change the color of the select arrow as it is getting an svg image. I tried to target the class of the svg image but was unable to change the color. Is there any way we can customize the select arrow using this package?

Below is the link to the sandbox for dropdown.

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-taussig-16i6k?file=/src/App.js:52-78
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can create your own svg:

```
// save locally new_icon_down_dir.svg (edit "fill" to preferred color)
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  height="32"
  viewBox="0 0 32 32"
  width="32"
>
  <g id="background"><rect fill="none" height="32" width="32" /></g>
  <g id="arrow_x5F_down"><polygon fill="blue" points="2.002,10 16.001,24 30.002,10" /></g>
</svg>
```

Then override the src for the img element like so:

```
const image = document.getElementsByClassName("icon_down_dir");
image.src = "new_icon_down_dir.svg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution like below :-

Add customArrow prop as true

```
 <Multiselect
          ...
          showArrow
          customArrow={true}
 />
```

and then add the below css.

```
    span.icon_down_dir {
        background-image: ...;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
    }

    span.icon_down_dir:before {
        content: "";
    }
```

Used package version
multiselect-react-dropdown version: 2.0.22

Hope this will work.